# get LookupError: unknown encoding: ascii

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ascii, wolframalpha

I can almost get wolframalpha to run, however I am stuck on this error:
i am working on this since 2 days and now everything is working but this error coming

```
    texts = texts.encode('ascii’, ‘ignore')
LookupError: unknown encoding: ascii’, ‘ignore
```

my code is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wolframalpha
import sys


app_id='PR5756-H3EP749GGH'                                              

client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)

query = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
res = client.query(query)

if len(res.pods) > 0:
  texts = ""
pod = res.pods[1]
if pod.text:
 texts = pod.text
else:
 texts = "I have no answer for that"
# to skip ascii character in case of error
texts = texts.encode('ascii’, ‘ignore')
print ('texts')
```

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quote characters are not matching, you are using two different type of quotes `’` and `'`.

```
texts = texts.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Comment: No, the error is `LookupError` and not `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character`, it's about how he uses the character and not the fact it's being used.

Comment: hi i did it and its not showing that error but now its showing this error 

`  File "d.py", line 26
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: i just added this line to script

`texts = texts.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
print texts
else:
print "Sorry, I am not sure.”`

Comment: `Else` must follow an `if` scope, that might be your error.